# black screen on Install, cannot apply standard solutions

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, dell

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Alienware Aurora R9 (with NVIDIA card). When installing I had a black screen that was solved by adding 'nomodeset' in GRUB. Now when I boot I get a black screen but I have no access to the GRUB menu. When I boot with F12 I get another type of option menu (Dells bios?) with no option to edit and add nomodeset, at least no one that I am know.

I also tryied pressing ctrl+alt+f*.

At the moment I don't have access to anything besides the bios menu and no idea how to fix this. Any ideas?

Edit: Additional information
1) I see the Dell logo when I start
2) I have Nvidia 2080ti
3) I did not select any non-free drivers
4) No dual-boot, I erased everything and installed Ubuntu
4) If by live usb you mean the 'try ubuntu' option then yes, if I press the USB option then GRUB opens then only if I add nomodeset I can see everything normally.

[This is the menu I see when I boot. If I press Ubuntu I get directly a black screen, if I press the USB option I get the GRUB install menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgcRp.jpg)

Comment: Could you edit your post and give some more information: describe what you see when you boot your PC (e.g. dell logo - grub...), which nvidia card do you have, did you select non-free drivers... Normally you should see grub no matter which settings you've applied for your video card. Also, can you boot up using live-usb?

Comment: @wouter205 I added the info you wanted. Thank you for the help

Comment: I see it's installed in UEFI mode - from my experience I know some hardware does not boot well in UEFI. Could you turn it of and set it to bios/legacy (you should select bios setup from the screenshot you added, most of the time this setting is in a tab called something like security)

Comment: @wouter205 the UEFI option is greyed out so I cannot change it.

Comment: Isn't it protected with a password or pin? I don't have experience with Dell, but with HP f.e. you disable UEFI, reboot and need to enter the pin displayed on the screen just to make sure you intentionally disable UEFI (so it was not done by some malware..). Possibly with Dell it's a similar procedure.

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you switch to a TTY screen when the screen is black after booting up. Press ctrl + alt + F1 and see if you can log in to the terminal.

Comment: In the end I somehow managed to get into grub. Disabling secure boot helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Didn't really know what I was doing so I just tried random stuff and this is what ended up working, so maybe some of it was unnecessary.

I disabled secure boot then reinstalled in OEM mode. Finally I had the option to add grub into the boot options then when grub finally opened I could add nomodeset and everything was good.

Comment: Good you've managed to solve it yourself. Don't forget to mark your answer as the solution (possible in 2 days I think). One note: I think you mean you've re-installed it in BIOS mode not OEM mode, isn't it (OEM is for manufacturers of PC hardware)?

Comment: In the Ubuntu install option I picked OEM mod, and yes they said it is for manufacturers. As I said, I didn't really know what I was doing so I just tried random stuff until I finally got access to the GRUB menu and could finally fix the problem.